# IAP SKProduct not found

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I wrote an xCode Swift app for myself and put it on the app store just to see how it was done.

It has an in-app purchase that enables additional settings.

I get very few sales, but I have successfully processed sales and gotten paid.
Recently, (can't say when) the purchase logic broke.  No coding changes have been made.

My product id is correctly configured in App Store Connect.
In-App Purchase is turned on in the Capabilities section of xCode.

I've paired down the code to the essentials below.  Any insights would be appreciated.

```
//****************************************************************************************
// Issue an IAP request to return all Products that match the supplied set of Product IDs.
//****************************************************************************************
func getProductsFromApple(viewController: UIViewController) {
    enum myAppProductIdentifier: String {
            case consumable               = "com.tailorsoft.SongAnnouncer.consumable"
            case nonConsumable            = "com.tailorsoft.SongAnnouncer.nonConsumable"
            case autoRenewingSubscription = "com.tailorsoft.SongAnnouncer.autoRenewingSubscription"
            case nonRenewingSubscription  = "com.tailorsoft.SongAnnouncer.nonRenewingSubscription"
     }
     let myAppProductIdentifiers: Set = [myAppProductIdentifier.nonConsumable.rawValue]

     // myAppProductIdentifers contains:
             (offset: 0, element: "com.tailorsoft.SongAnnouncer.nonConsumable")

     let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: myAppProductIdentifiers)
     request.delegate = self
     request.start()
}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    //******************************************************************************************************
    // Delegate Method for IAP
    // Returns list of valid products found in App Store Connect that match the supplied set of Product IDs.
    // NOTE: App Store Connect has the following in-app purchase configured:
    //          Status:         Approved
    //          Product ID:  com.tailorsoft.SongAnnouncer.nonConsumable
    //******************************************************************************************************
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.appleSKProducts = response.products
  
        //*******************************************
        // response.products.count is equal to 0
        // why?
        //*******************************************
    }
{
```

Comment: Possible reasons are: a) your Apple Developer Program membership has expired; b) you have not accepted the latest version of the paid applications agreement in App Store Connect; c) The app needs to hold a strong reference of `SKProductRequest` once it's been issued. In your particular case the request gets deallocated immediately after it starts. Create a property in your `IAPService` class of type `SKProductRequest?` and assign the request to it so that it doesn't get deallocated unexpectedly. In the delegate method, reset it back to `nil`. Please let me know if any of these tips helped.

Comment: Thanks, Vadim.  I've answered my own question. :-)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Still, make sure to retain a strong reference to `SKProductsRequest`, otherwise it may not work reliably ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It wasn't code related.

Apple had issued an update to the App Store Connect paid apps agreement that I wasn't aware of.

Once I read and clicked agree the purchase functionality started working.

Apologies for the inconvenience.